# Como puedo buscar en un array desde otro array?

Tags: javascript, angular

Hola buenas tardes me gustaria saber si me podeis ayudar con esta duda,

como puedo buscar en un array desde otro array?
es decir yo tengo mi "array1" y mi "array2", con un conjunto de id en cada uno de ellos.

Array1-> tiene todos los ids;
`array1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]`
Array2-> tiene algunos.
    `array2=[1,3,4,8,9]`

Quiero buscar en el array1 que ids me faltan en array2, y crear un nuevo array (array3) con esos ids que me faltan

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. Para que podamos ayudarte agrega el código que tienes hasta el momento. Saludos.

Comment: en php podrias hacer un array_diff... No se si existe algo parecido en javascript...

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes hacer con `filter` para filtrar los elementos del primere array e `includes` para ver si un valor está dentro del array:

```
const array3 = array1.filter(value => !array2.includes(value));
```

Te quedaría en array3 todos los elementos del array1 que no están en el array2. En tu caso:

```
[2, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11]
```

El funcionamiento es utilizar la función `filter` para crear un array con elementos de otro array (array1) pero solo los que cumplan una determinada condición. En este caso solo se incluirían los elementos de array1 que no estén incluidos en el array2.

Answer (score 0):

Sería algo así:

```
const result = Array.from(new Set(array1.concat(array2)));
```

Con esto consigues un nuevo array que contiene los valores de los otros dos sin duplicar.

Saludos!